# Can not center image/avatar within Card

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Please help, its driving me crazy, feels like this should be so simple.

I can't seem to `center` an image/avatar in the middle of a `Card` component I'm trying to create.

Tried `alignText` ,`alignItems`, `alignContent`, `justify`.

I even tried  which worked but is obviously now obsolete...

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Dankirk from '../assets/img/dankirk.jpg'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  card: {
    width: "100%",
    minHeight: "150px",
    borderRadius: "0px",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: 10,
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
  },
});

export default function SimpleCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (

    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.container}>
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
          Test
        </Typography>
            <Avatar alt="avatarimage" src={name} className={classes.avatar} />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
    </div>
    </div>

  );
}
```

Image just stays to the left...

Comment: I would suggest flexbox. This is a great guide to centering with CSS https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: please add a codesanbox link so we can debug and check whats is going wrong. thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Can you try display flex:

```
style={{ justifyContent: "center", display: "flex" }}
```

Comment: If you want to center it horizontal and vertical, use `align-items: center` as well. Or in this case `alignItems: "center"`

Comment: Also, keep ```flexDirection: "column"```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use margin: "auto" like this:

<Avatar alt="Travis Howard" src="/students/gaby.svg" sx={{ height: "64px", width: "64px", margin: "auto" }} />

Answer (score 0):

Also try do add lineHeight: 0, letterSpacing: 0 to Avatar component